# Swift Line Command : xcrun swiftc

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, command-line

I'm using the swift line command to comiple my code Client.Swift . when i compile i'm getting the object Client.o

Now, i would to link the Client .o with my static library libjjeromqi386.a in order to generate the excutable app. To do this i enter this line command :

$ xcrun swiftc -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -o app Client.o -target i386-apple-ios8.3 -import-objc-header /Users/systems/pMaster/ProjetXcode/SimpleSwift/Bridging-Header.h -L/Users/systems/pMaster/ProjetXcode/Librairies -Xcc -I/Users/systems/pMaster/ProjetXcode/j2objc-0.9.6/include -Xcc -I/Users/systems/pMaster/ProjetXcode/jjeromqObjC/src/main -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include

i get the error :

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgZeromqZMQ", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo12OrgZeromqZMQ in Client.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgZeromqZMQ_Context", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo20OrgZeromqZMQ_Context in Client.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgZeromqZMQ_Socket", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo19OrgZeromqZMQ_Socket in Client.o
  "_OrgZeromqZMQ_contextWithInt_", referenced from:
      __TFC6Client4main6ClientfS0_FT_T_ in Client.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Any help please ?

You should know that the library libjjeromqi386 is i386 architecture, as the client.o too

Thanks in advance